# How to implement multiple inheritance using jQuery extend

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiple-inheritance, extend

According to Douglas Crockford I could use something like http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html (with a little bit of tweaking)... but I am interested in jQuery way of doing it. Is it good practice using $.extend ?

I have 4 classes :

```
            var A = function(){ } 
            A.prototype = {
                name : "A",
                cl : function(){
                    alert(this.name);
                }
            }
            var D = function(){} 
            D.prototype = {
                say : function(){
                    alert("D");
                }
            }

            var B = function(){} //inherits from A
            B.prototype = $.extend(new A(), {
                name : "B"
            });

            var C = function(){} //inherits from B and D
            C.prototype = $.extend(new B(), new D(), {
                name : "C"
            });


            var o = new C();

            alert((o instanceof B) && (o instanceof A) && (o instanceof C)); //is instance of A, B and C 
            alert(o instanceof D); //but is not instance of D
```

So, i can call every method, property ... from A, B, C and D. Problem comes, when I want to test if o is instance of D? How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Just a note, in practice, in a duck typed language, you rarely care if an object is instanceof something. Why are you checking instanceof D? Note that usually what you really need are http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin

Comment: Multiple inheritance does not work with `instanceof`, since objects can only have a linear prototype chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it good practice using $.extend

`$.extend` is useful for singletons but for prototypes is not ideal.

Using `Object.create` (or Crockford's polyfill) you can easily create classes like this. I'm using `$.extend` to simply process the properties and give them default values and the module pattern to keep it well organized. Hope this helps:

```
// Helper that makes inheritance work using 'Object.create'
Function.prototype.inherits = function(parent) {
  this.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
};

var Person = (function PersonClass() {

  var _defaults = {
    name: 'unnamed',
    age: 0
  };

  function Person(props) {
    $.extend(this, props, _defaults);
  }

  Person.prototype = {
    say: function() {
      return 'My name is '+ this.name;
    }
  };

  return Person;

}());

var Student = (function StudentClass(_super) {

  Student.inherits(_super); // inherit prototype

  var _defaults = {
    grade: 'untested'
  };

  function Student(props) {
    _super.apply(this, arguments); // call parent class
    $.extend(this, props, _defaults);
  }

  Student.prototype.say = function() {
    return 'My grade is '+ this.grade;
  };

  return Student;

}(Person));

var james = new Student({ name: 'James', grade: 5 });

console.log(james instanceof Student); // true
console.log(james instanceof Person); // true
```

Comment: very good example. tnx. it gave me new point of view on things. i've decided to stick with method described here :  http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html for now. but is there a way to use multiple inheritance at once with clean coding?

Answer (score 1):

An object has only one prototype, so you cannot make it an instance of two other types with one call.

`$.extend(new B(), new D(), ...` creates an object that is an instance of B. Then all properties of D are copied to the newly created object. But the object will still be an instance of B.

Using `$.extend` is neither good nor bad per se. But you are bound to jQuery, which makes your code less reusable. And you have to be aware of the fact that `$.extend` overwrites properties with the same name, which might or might not be what you want.

Comment: tnx for the answer! i thought there is a way to use multiple inheritance at once with clean coding?

Comment: Well, multiple inheritance is the opposite of clean coding ;) If instanceof is not absolutely necessary for you then your code is fine. There is no way, sorry.

Comment: can you look under answers. If you could inspect it... EDIT: ok i can not answer my own question. so here is ouside link : http://jsfiddle.net/Rfzzr/

Comment: That's essentially what `$.extend` does. The difference is that this code creates a new type.